# Trying to understand EWS redirection failure

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

I'm tinkering with connection to our work Exchange thing from Linux and trying to understand what is happening with the autodiscover process.

I start with

```
curl -u 'xxxx' https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

and get back a page that I've created a service and says to point at

```
https://am3pr05mb0677.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com:444/EWS/Services.wsdl
```

but dns lookup (dig) on am3pr05mb0677.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com fails, as does digging for eurprd05.prod.outlook.com and prod.outlook.com. All I get back is a SOA record.

Basically, WTH is going on? I've googled my fingers off and found lots of references to eurprd05.prod.outlook.com but they all seem to be from people who are not having any trouble resolving the name. Why me?!

Ultimately, this is aiming at command line room booking function for work, but that's a long way off at the moment!

Comment: You should just be submitting any of your EWS SOAP requests to https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx . If you accessing a Mailbox other then your own you should add the X-AnchorMailbox header.

Comment: Do you have access to the user's e-mail address and password so that you can put it in the command line, or are you using impersonation?

Comment: @Tholle At the moment I'm using my own username and password, which I'm including in the actual command line in place of 'xxxx'. If Glen Scales is correct then I've completely misunderstood the purpose of that initial URL, although that doesn't explain why the returned page has a bogus URL in it.

Comment: I don't understand the bogus URL either to be honest, but either way, the URL you are trying to Autodiscover against is the URL you will end up with as the result of it. I would suggest using a library for autodiscovering if you really need it, since it is a real hassle. If you only want to use Office365 Online, you already have your answer: https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx